# laravel blade reducing code repetition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have code in my blade layout file and blade view for two tables. Is there a way to reduce the amount of code I am repeating ? Below is the code in my layout file.
Is there a way to have the first table in the layout file and then pass it different variables to create multiple different tables in the blade view file? 
Basically can I use the code for the first table in the layout to recreate the second table in the blade view file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<table border = "1", cellspacing = "2", align = center>
<tr> <td> <strong> ID </strong></td> <td><strong> Time </strong></td><td>  <strong> Note </strong></td></tr>
<!-- blade for loop  -->
@for ($i=0; $i <$countOfUniqueDate[$uniqueDates[0]]; $i++)

<tr><td> {{ $number[$i] ->id }} </td><td> {{ $number[$i]->timevalue }} </td> <td> {{ $number[$i]->note }} </td></tr>
@endfor
</table>

@yield('table')

//I would like to get rid of the below code by reusing the above table code 
// to recreate the second table 

<br><br><br>
<table border = "1", cellspacing = "2", align = center>
<tr> <td> <strong> ID </strong></td> <td><strong> Time </strong></td><td> <strong> Note </strong></td></tr>
@for($i= $countOfUniqueDate[$uniqueDates[0]]; $i < ($countOfUniqueDate[$uniqueDates[0]] + $countOfUniqueDate[$uniqueDates[1]]); $i++)

 <tr><td> {{ $number[$i] ->id }} </td><td> {{ $number[$i]->timevalue }} </td><td> {{ $number[$i]->note }} </td></tr>
 @endfor

</table>
<br><br><br><br><br>

@yield('table2')
</body>

<br><br>
</html>
```

Here is the code in my blade view file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



@extends("layouts.practice")
@section('table')
@stop


<p align="center">
<a href="https://villageprintwebapp.app/writeNote"> Add a comment </a>
</p>

</html>
```

I am also able to display both tables without referencing section('table2') but not sure how this is working.

Comment: I don't get it. Could please be more specific what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I can not get it too

Comment: is there a way I can make the second table by reusing the code for the first table ?

Comment: maybe use `@include('table', $paramsAsArray)` instead of `@yield`?

Comment: so $paramsAsArray would be a variable that is used in creating the table ?

Comment: Is this your answer? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#control-structures -- scroll down to "Including Sub-Views"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever code repeating you can add the same in another blade file and include the same inside wherever you use the same

@include('viewname',$params)

params will be an array , key value pairs which you want to pass to the particular segment of code in the new blade template

Comment: I am trying to do something like this to create the second table. I have a variable $startCount and $startCountArray created in a controller and passed to the template file. In the below code I am trying to reset these variables to a different value to create a different table. @include('layouts.practice', ["startCount" => $countOfUniqueDate[0], "startCountArray"
=> $countOfUniqueDate[1]])

Comment: I got this to work  after playing around with it. @include('layouts.practice', ["startCount" => $countOfUniqueDate[0], "startCountArray" => $countOfUniqueDate[1]]). Thanks for your help I was struggling with this for a while